# enhance.js error in internet explorer

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use enhance.js to load scripts only on desktops :

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/426954/allora/index.html

```
<script>
enhance({
loadScripts: [
{media: 'screen', excludemedia: 'screen and (max-device-width: 480px)', src: 'js/jquery-1.5.min.js'},
{media: 'screen', excludemedia: 'screen and (max-device-width: 480px)', src: 'js/jquery.cycle.lite.min.js'},
{media: 'screen', excludemedia: 'screen and (max-device-width: 480px)', src: 'js/script.js'},
]       
}); 
</script>
```

but I get this error in Internet Explorer 8 :

Webpage error details

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;
>   MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;
>   Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR
>   2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E;
>   Media Center PC 6.0) Timestamp: Sun, 6
>   Feb 2011 13:05:48 UTC
>
> Message: 'media' is null or not an
>   object Line: 7 Char: 8741 Code: 0 URI:
>   http://dl.dropbox.com/u/426954/allora/js/enhance.min.js

thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have an extra comma.

IE 7 and 8 consider there will be an additionnal undefined element in your array.

sidenote: IE6 will get the syntax error and others browsers will ignore it